# Why is numpy.dot() returning a matrix object when it should be returning array in my code?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing code for **locally weighted linear regression** from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/locally-weighted-linear-regression-in-python-3d324108efbf#:%7E:text=In%20Locally%20weighted%20linear%20regression,(i)%20%27s%20data.).

In it the line of code for making prediction at a specific point is:
`pred = np.dot(point_, theta)` where `point_` is an array of shape `(2,)` and for e.g is `[-3, 1]` where `-3` is the point where I would like to make the prediction and `1` is the bias term.

```py
def predict(X, y, point, tau):
    """
    Predict the target value for a given point using weighted regression.

    Args:
        X: Input features dataset.
        y: Target values dataset.
        point: The point of interest.
        tau: Bandwidth parameter.

    Returns:
        float: Predicted target value.
    """
    m = X.shape[0]
    X_ = np.append(X, np.ones(m).reshape(m, 1), axis=1)
    point_ = np.array([point, 1])

    w = wm(point_, X_, tau) # function that returns a diagonal weight matrix

    theta = np.linalg.pinv(X_.T * (w * X_)) * (X_.T * (w * y))
    
    print("Data type of point_ ",type(point_))

    pred = np.dot(point_, theta)
    
    return pred
```

Now

```
print("Data type of point_ ",type(point_))
```

gives Data type of `point_`  `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

This above function is called by the following function:

```py
def plot_predictions(X, y, tau, nval):
    """
   
        nval: Number of points to predict for.
    """
    X_test = np.linspace(-3, 3, nval)
    preds = []

    for point in X_test:
        pred = predict(X, y, point, tau)
        print("Data type of pred: ",type(pred))
        preds.append(pred)

    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(nval, 1)
    preds = np.array(preds).reshape(nval, 1)

    # Plot the original data points and predicted values
    plt.plot(X, y, 'b.')  # Blue dots for original data points
    plt.plot(X_test, preds, 'r.')  # Red dots for predicted values
    plt.show()

# Plot the predictions
plot_predictions(X, y, 0.08, 100)
```

In this case,

```py
print("Data type of pred: ",type(pred))
```

gives the output Data type of `pred`:  `<class 'numpy.matrix'>`. Printing out its shape gives `(1, 1)`.

**From my understanding, pred should not be a matrix. It should be an array because `point_` has the shape `(2,)` and `theta` has the shape `(2,1)`. Since one of the arguments being passed is not a 2d array or matrix, so the returned value is also not a matrix.**

Why is `pred` a matrix? Also, the program runs completely fine with no error. But I do not understand why matrix is being returned.

I wrote a small program separately with the same shapes of the arrays as `point_` and `theta`.

```py
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([1, 2])  # Shape: (2,)
array2 = np.array([[3], [4]]) # Shape: (2,1)
result = np.dot(array1, array2)

print("Result:")
print(result)
print("Shape of the result:", result.shape)
print("Data type of the result:", type(result))
```

Output:

```py
Result:
Shape of the result: (1,)
Data type of the result: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Here, `np.dot()` seems to run fine, but not in the locally weighted code.

Comment: You introduced a matrix *somewhere*. It's not `point_`, but that's just one of many objects you have here.

Comment: Hard to reply without a [mre], and any debugging information (printing `type(point)` is pointless (no pun intended) since we already know it is a ndarray. It would be more interesting to know its `dtype`, and its `.shape`). We don't know what `wm` does for example. Or what `point` is. You tell us they are matrix and scalar. But obviously some ot fhe things you believe are not true, so we need to see it, in an example (a [mre] is what you tried to do at the end. But since it is working in your example, that is proof that problem is in the asumption you made to build it)

Comment: Note that if `w` was really a diagonal matrix, whatever its size (you didn't say anything about this hugely important detail), then `(w*X_)` should just fail, since you cannot multiply (element-wise multiply) arrays unless they have the same shape (or broadcastable, with some axis being size 1).

Comment: And even if it is not failing (meaning that `w` is in reality a non-square matrix, of same shape as `X_` — that might include a diagonal square part, but it not strictly speaking diagonal, since diagonal matrix are square by definition), then `w*X_` has to be the same shape as `X_` (whatever `w` either the operation fails, or it returns something of the shape of `X_`)

Comment: Meaning that `X_.T * (w * X_)` has to be a n×n matrix (assuming shape of `X` is m×n). So is `np.linalg.pinv(X_.T * (w * X_))` therefore (so it is not really needed to use `pinv` here, since its argument is squared). And then, same reasoning for the whole `theta`: it has to be a matrix (a n×n I would say, tho I fail to see how `(X_.T * (w * y))` could be n×n. So it is ambiguous here. First part says it is n×n, second that it is n×m. Both can't be true simultaneously, unless m is either n or 1. But point is, `theta` is a matrix

Comment: Calling `dot` with `point_` on it, should work only if one of its dimension is 2 or 1. But well, anyway, I shouldn't be trying to play Sherlock to reverse engineer what those data are. Post a [mre]

Comment: So `wm` is in the linked article.  And makes the `matrix`

Answer (score 1):

```
w = wm(point_, X_, tau)
```

`w` is a [np.matrix](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). It was generated in `wm()` by this line of code:

```
w = np.mat(np.eye(m))
```

Make it an array instead. When you multiply a matrix by an array the result is a matrix, because a matrix is just an array which an only do some of the array things. Don't use `np.mat` for anything.